# SSIS - import file with columns populated like sub-headers (omitted on some rows)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am importing an Excel file which is formatted like a report - that is some columns are only populated once for each group of rows that it belongs to, such as:

```
    CaseID  |Date     |Code
     157207 |         |
            |8/1/2012 |64479
            |8/1/2012 |Q9967
            |8/1/2012 |99203
```

I need to capture one of these group headers (CaseID, in the example above) and use it for subsequent rows where the field is blank, then save the next value that I encounter.
 I have added a variable (User::CurrentCaseId) and a Script transform, with the following code:

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    string newCaseId;

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        if (!Row.CaseIDName_IsNull && Row.CaseIDName.Length > 0)
            newCaseId = Row.CaseIDName;
        else
            newCaseId = "DetailRow";
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
            if (newClaimNumber != "DetailRow")
                Variables.CurrentCaseId = newCaseId;
    }
```

Basically, I am trying to read the value when present and save it in this variable.  I use a conditional split to ditch the rows that only have the CaseID and then use a derived column to put the variable value into a new column to complete the detail row.
Alas, the value is always blank (placed a data viewer after the derived column).  I modified the script to always set the variable to a fixed string - the derived column is still blank.

This seemed like a good plan...  I received some feedback in the MS forums that you can't set a variable value and use its new value within the same Data Flow Task.  If that is so, the only solution I can think of is to write the CaseID out to a table when present and read it back in when absent.  I really hate to do that with several million rows (multiple Excel worksheets).  Any better ideas?

Best,
Scott

Comment: For a solution outside of SSIS, a short Excel macro will prepare the file for import:
'Sub CopyClaimNumber()  Dim CurrentClaim As String
    Sh1 = "Sheet1"
    LastRow1 = Sheets(Sh1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set Source = Sheets(Sh1).Range("A3:B" & LastRow1)
    For Each C In Source
        If C.Value <> "" Then
            CurrentClaim = Mid(C.Text, 1, (InStr(1, C.Text, "/",vbTextCompare) - 2))
        Else
            C.Value = CurrentClaim
        End If
    Next C
End Sub'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a good starting point for you.

1. I used the following file as the source. Saved it into C:\Temp\5.TXT

> ```
> CaseID  |Date     |Code
> 157207  |         |
>       |8/1/2012 |64479
>       |8/1/2012 |Q9967
>       |8/1/2012 |99203
> 157208  |         |
>       |9/1/2012 |77779
>       |9/2/2012 |R9967
>       |9/3/2012 |11203
> ```

1. Put a DFT on the Control Flow surface.
2. Put  Script Component as Source on the DFT

   3.1. Go to Inputs and Outputs section

   3.2. Add Output. Change it name to MyOutput.

   ```
    3.2.1 Add the following output columns - CaseID, Date, Code
    3.2.1 The data types are four-byte unsigned integer [DT_UI4], string [DT_STR], string [DT_STR]
   ```
3. Now go to Scripts // Edit Script. Put the following code. Make sure to add

> using System.IO;

to the namespace area.

```
    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\5.txt");

    int iRowCount = 0;
    string[] fields = null;
    int iCaseID = 0;
    string sDate = string.Empty;
    string sCode = string.Empty;

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (iRowCount == 0)
        {
            iRowCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            fields = line.Split('|');
            //trim the field values
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
            {
                fields[i] = fields[i].Trim();
            }

            if (!fields[0].Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                iCaseID = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                MyOutputBuffer.AddRow();

                MyOutputBuffer.CaseID = iCaseID;
                MyOutputBuffer.Date = fields[1];
                MyOutputBuffer.Code = fields[2];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

1. Testing your code: Add a Union All components right beneath where you put the Script component. Connect the output of the Script component to the Union All component. Put data viewer.

Hopefully this should help you. Please let us know. I responded to a similar question today; please check that one out as well. That may help in solidfying the concept - IMHO.

Comment: Thank you.  I had not thought of using a script component as the source, but clearly the only way to go for an SSIS solution due to batch processing of data.